# php echo data using <?=

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are PHP short tags acceptable to use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

I have a question using

`<?=$info ?>` rather than `<?php echo $info ?>` when is `<?=` appropriate to use or has it be deprecated with 5.0

Comment: I like Paolo Bergantino's answer from that question: "I'm too fond of <?=$whatever?> to let it go. Never had a problem with it. I'll wait until it bites me in the ass. " :)

Comment: @Pekka: I have done away with this habit ever since I knew about its limitations and possible security holes: http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/01/12/php-short-open-tag/ :)

Comment: I wish they hadn't deprecated this.  <?php echo ... ?> is so much more verbose.  I can understand deprecating <% %> but <?= ... ?> makes it easier to treat PHP as a templating tool.

Comment: @Sarfraz: Following the logic of the article you linked to, the same "hole" exists for long tags if somehow PHP is disabled on the server. In my opinion, short tags shouldn't be used for only one reason: portability (having said that I've never come across a server that didn't allow short tags).

Comment: @emurano: They didn't deprecate this.  They deprecated `<?` (From my understanding of it)...   And for my $0.02, I can't stand short tags.  I don't know why.  I wouldn't tell you not to use them, but I just can't stand them (same with alternative control structure syntax)...

Comment: The question whether we shall or shall not use short_tags may be rephrased to whether PHP is a good candidate for a template engine. And as I think that PHP mustn't be used as a TE I obviously recommend against using short_tags.

Comment: They did not deprecate anything. It is just no longer enabled by default.

Comment: Hey @ircmaxell my assumption that <?= was deprecated is because <?= doesn't work unless you enable short_open_tag in php.ini; this directive also enables <? ?>, which is what we all agree should be deprecated.  Regardless I've started replacing <?= with <?php echo in all code I control.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<?=` must be marked as enabled in the config file, it's optional syntax I think...

Comment: Optional syntax and also something that is going to be deprecated eventually. I would really get in the habit of using <?php echo $var;?>

Answer (score 1):

Just be aware that if you move your code to another server where short tags are disabled, you may have a lot of work on your hands.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the short_open_tag configuration setting enabled, you can use this. Generally, short tags are looked down upon, for readability and compatability's sake (if this is disabled by default in a  later version, if you have to move your website to another server where this option is disabled,  etc.)

However, if you can use it, it's not bad to use at all. If all you need to do is echo something, then use it if you wish.